# Is "pre-Industrial-Revolution" spelled and hypenated correctly?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization

I found this quote online:

> The hackish senses of "engine" are actually close to its original, **pre-Industrial-Revolution** sense of a skill, clever device, or instrument (the word is cognate to "ingenuity").
>
> -- [definition of engine on FOLDOC](http://foldoc.org/Engine)

Is "pre-Industrial-Revolution" capitalized, and are the hypens in the correct place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the style guide in use, either *pre-Industrial-Revolution* or *pre-Industrial Revolution* could be acceptable, but the latter form is surely more common.

---

*Industrial Revolution* is a proper noun as it refers to a specific historical epoch (~1760-1840 in Britain, different years elsewhere), and both words are always capitalized.

One use of hyphens (and en dashes) is to join related words to remove ambiguity. For example, a *little-used car lot* would be a car park that is usually empty, whereas a *little used-car lot* could be a small lot on which used cars are sold, and a *little-used-car lot* is perhaps someplace to find pre-owned [Peel P-50s](http://www.topgear.com/uk/tv-show/series-10/episode-3).

Hyphens are also used when creating a compound word with a prefix or suffix unless the unhyphenated form has been accepted into the language: *company-wide* but *nationwide*, *post-capitalist* but *postgraduate*. (Many words evolve from hyphenated to conjoined forms; thus you may read of a *preeminent supervillain's anteroom* in one place and a *pre-eminent super-villain's ante-room* in another.)

So, if there is a danger that the reader would parse *pre-Industrial Revolution* as [pre-Industrial]+[Revolution] instead of [pre-]+[Industrial Revolution], I could see an argument for keeping both hyphens. But *Industrial Revolution* is a set phrase, and I think there is little chance of confusion. [Chicago avers](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf) that the second hyphen is unnecessary (but says to use an en dash, as with *pre–Vietnam War*). [APA avers on the other hand](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/when-use-hyphen.aspx) that each word in a compound should be hyphenated. Neither the MLA nor the *[Economist](http://www.economist.com/style-guide/hyphens)* seem to address this specific case.

Also see

- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/how-do-i-hyphenate-an-open-form-compound-word-with-another-that-should-be-hyphen
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105866/capitalization-and-hyphenation-for-prefixed-adjectives-derived-from-proper-names

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. See the following text from the [APA Style guidelines](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/when-use-hyphen.aspx):

> Also use hyphens for
>
> - Compounds in which the base word is capitalized: pro-Freudian
> - a number: post-1970
> - an abbreviation: pre-UCS trial
> - more than one word: non-achievement-oriented students